# JS. Перебор массива с функциями

Tags: javascript, массивы, переменные, перебор

Доброго времени суток всем! Перейду сразу к сути.

Есть некий массив:

```js
let zaprosi = ["Запрос1", "Запрос2", "Запрос3"]
```

Ввод в поисковую строку + клик по кнопке:

```js
document.querySelector('input#search').value ='ЗАПРОСЫ ИЗ МАССИВА ПО ОЧЕРЕДИ';
document.querySelector('button#search-icon-legacy').click();
```

Также есть код [*Код001*] (ищет по тексту совпадения - кликает, если не нашел - прокручивает страницу и снова ищет):

```js
const findAndClick = (channelName, delay) => {
  const blocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div#channel-info'));

  let elem = blocks.find((item) => item.innerText.trim().toLowerCase() == channelName.toLowerCase())

  if (elem) {
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('a#thumbnail').click();
  } else {
    window.scrollBy(0, 5500)

    setTimeout(() => {
      findAndClick(channelName, delay)
    }, delay)
  }
}

findAndClick('НАЗВАНИЕ КАНАЛА', 3000)
```

Собственно, мне нужно всё это соединить, что последовательность была такая:

1. Взял значение "Запрос1" из переменной **zaprosi**
2. Вставил в **document.querySelector('input#search').value='ЗНАЧЕНИЕ';**
3. Кликнул по кнопке **document.querySelector('button#search-icon-legacy').click();**
4. Выполнил "Код001"
5. Далее взял значение "Запрос2" из переменной **zaprosi** и по кругу... Потом также "Запрос3".

*Буду благодарен за помощь!*

Comment: что мешает друг за другом это все вызывать?

Comment: Мешает незнание как это сделать...